# Piezo electric water vaporizer

Tags: piezoelectricity

I'm interested in a module that I've seen today and is a cold water vaporizer. I turns water to steam without heating it.

Anyways this module needs kind of oscillating circuit to work properly and they didn't mention the specifics of that oscillator cause they are selling the full premade device with an expensive price, so does anyone know how to make that circuit?

Link to product: [https://eshop.eca.ir/ماژول-و-سنسور-بخار-سرد/1636-پیزو-الکتریک-مخصوص-بخار-آب-سرد.html](https://eshop.eca.ir/%D9%85%D8%A7%DA%98%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%AF/1636-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%B2%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%84%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%85%D8%AE%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B5-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D8%A8-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%AF.html)

Comment: Perhaps they don’t give the details so their business works and they get a return on their investment...

Comment: to be pedantic, the device does not turn water into steam, but rather vapor. Those devices are called ultrasonic vaporizer.

Comment: A search for **vaporizer** will give you better results from thousands of distributors including all the neccessary electronics for less money.

Comment: *I turns water to steam without heating it* That's not what happens! What it does is make "mist" consisting of very small droplets of water. To create steam you would need to turn the liquid water into gas and that requires a lot of heat.

Answer (score 2):

The device is called a **nebulizer** or **atomizer**.

It's just generally just a self-resonant Colpitts oscillator with a single power transistor and some passives (including a couple inductors). There may be some additional circuitry to turn it off if the water level drops.

I suggest you study the *prior art* in US patent [4996502](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/9e/ac/d7/50e64669189009/US4996502.pdf) assigned to Japan's TDK Corporation.

[image]

The droplet size is inversely related to the operating frequency (also the mechanical resonant mode of the piezoelectric element). Typically for consumer units a frequency around 1.5-1.7MHz is used, which generates droplets of a few microns in diameter.

Comment: Hint: if you're experimenting with the idea of determining the exact frequency (barring an integer factor) by trying to find a distance between piezo emitter and a reflector at which standing waves form:$$\\$$ do **not** use your finger as reflector. It hurts.